# Proguard and Google Analytics exporting apk issue

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

When I try to export my APK with Google Analytics and Proguard activated I have this problem.

I have added to my conf the this condition ->

```
  -keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

And this is console output

```
  Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Item
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Transaction
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$4: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Item
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$4: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Item
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$5: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Transaction
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$5: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Transaction
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegate: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Transaction
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegate: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.Item
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
    [2013-10-26 19:25:17 - UploadToServer] Warning: com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl: can't find referenced class com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your;

```
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

and add these 2 lines to your prpguard.cfg

```
-keep class com.google.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.google.** {*;}
```

If you still get error add this line too.

```
-dontwarn com.google.**
```